# Drude model vs Lorentz model, what differences between the both and their limits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, material-science

In order to study the interaction of a strong laser field with a noble gas cluster or metal clusters, I am using the nanoplasma model proposed by Detmire. 
We need to define some properties of nanoparticle using the Drude model or Lorentz model, as dielectric permittivity, and plasma frequency. Is there a difference between both models? Is there a book that treats these kinds of problems for different materials (metals, insulators, and semiconductors) ?

Comment: Roughly speaking, the Drude model models electric conductivity of metals, while the Lorentz model models refraction/reflection phenomena when light interacts with electrons in molecules.

Comment: The Drude model concerns just metals where they are considered free in the lattice formed the arranged ions. So the electrons easily can move under an external field. Which means we can easily heat or create a current in the metal. In contrast for insulators of semiconductor is not the case, the elecrons are more attached to lattice ions, they can oscillate under an external field but not too much as in the metal crystal. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yeah, only semiconductors are tricky, some electrons there under favorable conditions can form DC current too.

Comment: You're right. Semiconductors are in between and depend strongly on the surrounding temperature.